# Binding to Non-Existing (Future) Queue

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Is it at all possible to declare a binding between an existing exchange and a non-existing queue, so that when the queue (eventually) gets created by some other means in the future messages will start to get forwarded to it?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it at all possible to declare a binding between an existing exchange and a non-existing queue,

this is not possible.

you can only bind an exchange to an existing queue. you can only set up a consumer to get messages from an existing queue.

> so that when the queue (eventually) gets created by some other means in the future messages will start to get forwarded to it?

sort of... when you create a queue and binding, messages will start flowing to that queue. but only new messages. old messages are lost and will not flow to that queue.

If you are dynamically creating queues and bindings for your consumers, then your consumer should be the one to declare the queues. The problem, as you've probably run in to, is that you will not have any messages in the queue until the queue is created and bound.

If you need messages to be there before the consumer connects, then some other code needs to set up the queue and binding before the consumer connects and starts consuming from the queue.